# Windows - how to deny permission for all users from writing into a directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Every week, I have to take the backup of all the project files from SVN and put into my system and remove the write permission for everyone. So that it won't be changed accidentally in local system.In the next time, I have to delete these files and make a fresh copy from SVN. I am trying to automate this. I wrote a bat file for this. The code is below

```
    ::@echo off
    set folder="d:/delete_It"
    set user[0]="username@My_Company_WebSite.com"
    set user[1]="BLRTESLTP-username\Administrators"
    set user[2]="Everyone"
    set user[3]="domain\user"
    set user[4]="everyone"
    set user[5]="Authenticated Users"
    set user[6]="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users":
    set user[7]="My_Company_Network\username"
    set user[8]="BUILTIN\Administrators"
    set user[9]="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"
    set user[9]="BUILTIN\Users"
    
    icacls %folder% /T /grant %user[2]%:(OI)F
    icacls %folder% /T /grant %user[2]%:(OI)W
    
    cd /d %folder%
    rm -r -f /Q *.*
    del *.* /F /Q
    
    set svn="svn_Address"
    svn checkout %svn%  %folder%
    icacls %folder% /T /deny %user[2]%:(OI)(CI)W
```

Now the problem is even though I am removing the Write permission only, I couldn't open the folder "d:\delete_It". It is showing that I am not having permission to open the folder.The screenshot is below.

[image]

I opened the command prompt with admin privileges, and ran the script. But the effects were same.Can anybody say what is wrong? And how to achieve this?

Note: I am using "Windows 10 Pro" 64-bit OS

EDIT: Screenshots of the properties->security

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the ACL for the folder as a screenshot?  This will provide a better understanding of what the permissions actually are.

Comment: @Ramhound please check the edit

Comment: Your ACL has explicitly denied write permissions but hasn’t implicitly allowed read permissions